# Hashtag implementation supporting the HTML tags

Tags: textview, hashtag, spanned

I implemented the hashtag feature to my app using this sample [Hash-Tags-Android](https://github.com/rameshvoltella/Hash-Tags-Android)

I need to support the HTML tags along with hashtag. As of now this is not recognizing the HTML tags. Please share any link or sample code to help me.

I tried with [Html.fromHtml()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) but it not worked.

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution by the way? Thanks !

Comment: Yes it worked with the above library. There was a minor change in the library code.